# listening problem about linking

Tags: listening

In the video on Youtube at 0:16, the speaker seemed forget to read out "and", I only hear "liked a challenging came up", rather than speak "liked a challenge and came up"?

More examples like 0:05, I only hear " dəd ventures"  rather than clear pronunciation.

I am very puzzled, the pronunciation of single word and the word in a sentence are quite different, how can native speaker tell the difference? Almost all the English language learner has this problem, how can I solve it?

My question: please analyze the examples I mentioned, and try to give us possible tips
Thanks a million！

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skM37PcZmWE

Comment: I too believe that there should be a conjunction. Non-native ears here!

Comment: If you listen to it carefully you will notice **and** is pronounced very weakly right after a challenge. It is not challenging. It is **challenge + and** that you heard as **challenging**.

Comment: To the native ear the conjunction **and** is clearly heard, however it is pronounced "**nd**" not distinctly "**and**". The speaker is 1) slightly nasal in diction and 2) has a British accent, with of which may effect your hearing of what he is saying.  He also pronounces "**nd**"venture for "**adventure**".  How to understand this accent better? Maybe hang out with Brits, particularly southern Brits, more.

Comment: Hello,Peter. Thank you for your answer.Can you give me other examples? For example, “...and the ,,," what will you read that?Thanks a million！

Comment: @Peter No, there's no /d/ there at all, I don't think. English speakers don't usually put a /d/ in the word and unless it's stressed or it is before a pause. Our brains like to insert it for us when we listen though!

Comment: @Peter You might be hearing an epenthetic /g/ in there possibly. I can't hear it my self at all, but ...

Comment: @Peter I've solved that, Thanks again. Could you please help me in the beginning, "60-second adventures in thought". I have relistened the video for many times, but I only hear: secon d ventures. I don't know if I am right. Please analyze it. Thanks a million！

Comment: @Peter I have the script. I mean how did the narrator speak "second adventures"?  I only hear: secon d ventures. I don't know if I am right.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there are three distinct problems here:

1. The narrator has a British accent.  If you are only used to American
   accents, there are distinct differences.
2. Words beginning with vowels often mush into the word before them.
3. Often-used conjunctions are not enunciated properly. (e.g. "Fish 'n'
   Chips")

Suggestions?

1. It sounds like the narrator is **David Mitchell**.  He's a famous
   comedian in Britain.  If you are having trouble with him in
   particular, there's a wealth of content on youTube.
2. Although I appreciate that it's hard to hear, there is usually
   enough of a pause between words for native speakers not to have
   problems.  Indeed, this example was crystal clear for me (a Brit). 
   I can only suggest this improves with exposure.
3. Poor enunciation is trickier. The word 'and' is pretty universally
   abused around Britain.  However, every conjugation I can think of
   gets shorted somewhere here.  I guess exposure is the key to this
   too.

Comment: Yes; I'm sure it is David Mitchell. It was crystal clear for me also - you just beat me to the post.

Comment: That makes a change! Usually I find after hitting submit that someone else has managed to get in before me.

Answer (score 3):

Those kinds of words that you learn about in grammar lessons instead of vocabulary lessons often have two sounds in English. The normal one is called the weak form. This is the form we usually use when the word isn't stressed. The other is called the strong form. The word *and* has a weak form. It sounds like this: /ən/. Notice that this word doesn't have a /d/ sound here.

However, the word /ən/ ends in an /n/-sound. The sound /n/ often changes according to the following consonant. Before /p, b, m, w/ it can become a /m/. Before /k/ and /g/ it can become a /ŋ/. In the original Poster's clip, the word *and* comes before the word came, /keɪm/. For this reason the /n/ in *and* has changed to a /ŋ/. What the OP is actually hearing is:

- tʃælɪndʒ əŋ keɪm

The reason *adventure* sounds strange is because it deosn't start with an /æ/, the sound we hear in *cat* it starts with /ə/, the sound at the beginning to the word *America*.

How do English speakers understand each other when the grammar words change so much? Well, part of the answer is that grammar words aren't actually very important for understanding at all. Native speakers can't understand most unstressed words when they aren't actually in a sentence. To show how easy it is to understand English without hearing the grammar words, think about the following situation. A two year child old comes to speak to you and says:

- WANT GO PARK! NOW!

You will probably understand that they want to go to the park. However if they come to you and say:

- I TO TO THE!

You won't understand them at all. These words are all from the same sentence:

- I **want** to **go** to the **park**.

We can understand a sentence mainly from the stressed information words. The grammar words don't make much difference to the meaning, and English speakers often decide what the grammar words are *after* they understand the sentence, not before! So don't try too hard to hear the grammar words carefully. Listen to the information words instead.

Comment: @Aracaria Could you please help me in the beginning, "60-second adventures in thought". I have relistened the video for many times, but I only hear: secon d ventures. I don't know if I am right. Please analyze it. Thanks a million！

Comment: It seems that you are very good at pronunciation problems. In what book can I grab this knowledge?

Comment: @OscarLiu Let me think about it. I'll get back to you on that.